# bbPress plugin moderator roles

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, bbpress

I want to add an override to the existing role of a bbPress moderator. I need:

1. super admin assign forum to moderator and moderator access only that plugin.
2. one forum to have multiple moderators
3. one moderator to have multiple forums
4. moderators can edit and delete that forum , topic , and reply.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: There are some changes in this direction in upcoming bbPress 2.6, so you might give it a try (latest version is RC5).